# Android 4.2 changes to Android 3.0 under Project in Eclipse

Tags: java, android

Yesterday when I imported my App it showed Android 4.2 But when I loaded my app it shows Android 3.0. Now my application is having an issue with the manifest. Any idea why?

[image]

Comment: What does your `project.properties` say you're targetted for?

Comment: Why are you posting the same question under different user IDs?  That is considered very bad behaviour on Stackoverflow.

Comment: I can't vote to close as the original question has no answers or upvotes but this user is repeating questions under different user IDs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18363043/receiving-style-error-in-xml-in-android-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not happen in general, i have also faced this few time in my early days. it might a problem because of eclipse or unintentional mistake. Don't worry about this too much.

Right click on your project ->> Properties ->> Android ->> select android 4.2 ->> ok

it will resolve the issue.